# FFT / PWELCH Matlab define sampling frequency

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, sampling, frequency-analysis

I have a TXT-Doc https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/428580/Probe_1.txt with analog values. I'm using FFT and Pwelch in Matlab to find the frequency of my analog signal. Theoreticly the frequency should be somewhere ~300 Hz. That's why i thought about an area of 0-500 Hz.

I tried fft:

```matlab
>> load pr_1.txt;
>> Fs = 1000; 
>> T = 1/Fs; 
>> L = length(pr_1);
>> FFT = fft(pr_1);
>> P2 = abs(FFT/L);
>> P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
>> P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
>> f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
>> plot(f,20*log10(P1))
```

and pwelch:

```matlab
>> len = 2050;
>> h = kaiser(len,4.53);
>> pwelch(pr_1,h,[],len,Fs)
```

Both is showing me the same answer: Peak at ~300 Hz.
But my question is how to I define the right sampling frequence Fs?
If i change Fs for example to Fs=10000 instead of Fs=1000 I'll get Peak Points at ~3000 Hz instead of 300 Hz. And if I change Fs = 500, the Peak results at 150 Hz. I have the problem to understand and define the right Fs.

Comment: First of all the nature of this question is signal processng wise and not programming. However, regarding FS, it is not that you define it, it is given by the device which is sampling the values and which are then saved to the textfile. In the moment you sample them you are considering them not anymore as continues but discretized in time (sampled), and this process is being done with a certain sampling rate. So the answer is, who ever gave you the file, ask him with which frequency your data was sampled.

Comment: Sorry putting it in the wrong thread. In the TXT-File I have give a frequency of 9997.4286613483 Hz. Do you mean this is the samling frequency?

Comment: Sorry, I cant answer this question. Not knowing where this file comes from and which kind of information it contains it is impossible to make any statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your provided file was generated by some measurement device, you can take the 3rd line

```
#  Aufnahmerate [Hz]: 9997.4286613483
```

as your sample rate Fs. This is a fixed rate which is defined by the capturing device, just as @Irreducible said. Therefore you can't randomly change it.

The header of the file tells you also more information: It says there are 100000 samples, which is true, and also if you multiply the timeinterval per sample (5th line) with the number of samples(100000, 2nd line), you get exactly the measurement duration (4th line). From this I assume, that these values are true.

---

For completeness/future reference: the top content of your file:

```
# 2019-08-26 15:38:49.661906
#  Anzahl Messwerte: 100000
#  Aufnahmerate [Hz]: 9997.4286613483
#  Messdauer [s]: 10.002572
#  Zeitintervall je Messpunkt [ms]: 0.10002572
2.820286226094503856e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.820286226094503856e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.820286226094503856e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.819642225722452267e+00
2.820286226094503856e+00
2.820608226282290687e+00
2.819964225907891198e+00
2.820286226094503856e+00
2.819964225907891198e+00
...
```

Comment: Hey. Thx, yeah Fs is 9997.4286613483 Hz. I plotted it now with FFT and Pwelch and trying to filter the noise from FFT to get a nice signal like pwelch. <https://ibb.co/DCSHJCs>